# Connection refuse by sailsjs - mysql locally

Tags: mysql, node.js, sails.js, mysql-workbench

I'm using

1. sailsjs 0.12.0
2. Nodejs 4.2.3 with mySql DB.

I connected with the remote mySql DB it is working fine but when
I'm trying to connect my sailsjs app to the MySQL local, I'm getting the error:

[image]

```
error: Error (E_UNKNOWN) :: Encountered an unexpected error
: Could not connect to MySQL:
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306
```

when I'm checking into the MySQL server in workbench it's working fine.

[image]

Comment: Try localhost instead of 127.0.0.1. otherwise you need to change the access entries in user table of mysql db. After it, stop the mysql service and again start it.

Comment: can you post the code `config/connection.js`